# SQL Server DB Designer/Editor - which one do you use?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I find it good in a few ways and frustrating sometimes.

Which one to you guys use? Preferably something I can try for sometime before I buy...

Comment: well - a great designer, and then also **FREE** - that's a bit tricky... some are great, but $$$$$ - other are free, but most often unusable IMO.

Comment: Yes I agree, may be a trial one which allows me to try it before I go for it would be great!

Comment: What are you trying to design - schemas or queries?  Can you be a little more specific?  There's a ton of design tools, but it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

- Designer: [NORMA/ORM plug in](http://www.orm.net/). This can also generate SQL
- Editor: I tend to use raw SQL and avoid the designer

To be honest, raw SQL is quicker than fannying around in the GUI.